# Use of \cals doesn't match its definition \calscommand

Tags: macros, errors

The following minimal working example employs a `cals` table in the document environment and works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

%document encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%geometry
\RequirePackage[a4paper, layoutwidth=10.5cm, layoutheight=20cm, noheadfoot, nomarginpar, margin=0mm, showcrop]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\geometry{layouthoffset=0.5\paperwidth-5.25cm}
\geometry{layoutvoffset=0.5\paperheight-10cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

%table
\RequirePackage{cals}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{calstable}
\makeatletter
\colwidths{{3.30cm}{1.95cm}{5.25cm}}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.8pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.8pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingT}{1.44ex}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{1em}
\brow \nullcell{tbl}\nullcell{tb}\nullcell{tbr}\spancontent{} \ht\cals@current@row=30mm \erow
\brow \alignC \nullcell{tbl}\nullcell{tbr}\spancontent{} \alignL \cell{} \ht\cals@current@row=22mm \erow
\makeatother
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

However, when I put the code in a `\newcommand` called `\calscommand` I get a `Use of \cals doesn't match its definition \calscommand` error:

```
\documentclass{article}

%document encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%geometry
\RequirePackage[a4paper, layoutwidth=10.5cm, layoutheight=20cm, noheadfoot, nomarginpar, margin=0mm, showcrop]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\geometry{layouthoffset=0.5\paperwidth-5.25cm}
\geometry{layoutvoffset=0.5\paperheight-10cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

%table
\RequirePackage{cals}
\newcommand{\calscommand}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{calstable}
\makeatletter
\colwidths{{3.30cm}{1.95cm}{5.25cm}}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.8pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.8pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingT}{1.44ex}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{1em}
\brow \nullcell{tbl}\nullcell{tb}\nullcell{tbr}\spancontent{} \ht\cals@current@row=30mm \erow
\brow \alignC \nullcell{tbl}\nullcell{tbr}\spancontent{} \alignL \cell{} \ht\cals@current@row=22mm \erow
\makeatother
\end{calstable}
}

\begin{document}
\calscommand
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

move

```
\makeatletter
```

before your definition and

```
\makeatother
```

after it. You need the  `@` to be a letter used in command names at the point of the definition where you use those commands, not inside the definition.

Comment: Moving `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to the correct positions indeed did the trick. Thank you very much, David!